# c++ conversion from (void*) to user-defined type

Tags: c++, class, pointers, void

I am trying to make a queue from a class and use it within that class
also I want to use the same queue in another class
so I tried to do something like this:

```
class myClass1;
queue<myClass1> q;
class myClass0 //a simple type
{
//do stuff
};
class myClass1 //a Complex type
{
//............. i'm using the q object
//overloading casting operator to myClass0
};
class myClass2 //a Complex type
{
//............. i'm using the q object
};
```

and the compiler (vs 2017) pop-up an error says that: use of undefined type 'myClass1' in this line `queue<myClass1> q;`

so I started to avoid using the class before it's declaration by defining the queue like this

```
queue<void*> q;
```

and with making the necessary changes, I never succeed in dereference the `void*` pointer to get my object back ex.

```
myClass1 c = *(myClass1*)q.front();
```

and gave me (run-time error), and that happens because of the myClass1 contains vectors and other complex types
so my question is how to hide the first error or how to dereference the `void*` pointer to get my object back?

Comment: sorry, can you refresh the page to see the edits

Comment: Why straight from `<myClass1>` to `<void*>`? Your first stop on the way should have been `<std::unique_ptr<myClass1>>`.

Comment: But I can't define an queue of my class before the class definition

Comment: You can't make a queue of an incomplete type, but `std::unique_ptr<myClass1>` and `myClass1*` are both complete even if `myClass1` isn't.

Comment: Break up the definition of `myClass1` to separate the methods. Then you should be able to define `queue<myClass1> q;` after the definition of the `myClass1`.

Comment: Do you need to use q in the class declarations, or just in the method definitions? And can you move said definitions into separate .cpp files?

Comment: so you are saying define the queue like this: `queue<myClass1*>` right?

Comment: That's almost what @Quentin is suggesting. He's just going a bit further and trying to relieve you of possible memory management problems by recommending the use of a smart pointer.

Comment: i can separate the implementation into separate .cpp file
But still i need to use the queue the methods implementation

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a separate file. Eg: http://ideone.com/kJJxBE

Comment: @user4581301 indeed, but don't forget `inline`!

Comment: okay i have another problem now

Comment: you have to know that the first class overloading a cast operator to another type 'myClass0'

Comment: and when i separate the implementation it gives my this error 'operator myClass0' is not a recognized operator or type

Comment: Can't help you much with that one. `myClass0` is unlisted. Sounds different enough that you may be better off with a new question. That said, no one has formally answered this one, so you can probably get away with an edit that piggy backs. A new question will get more eyes, though, and asking two question in one tends to collect "Too broad" close votes.

Comment: Another solution would be to have out-of-line bodies for functions in `myClass1` so `q` can go in between the class definition and the bodies